# WinFSP and SSHFS Multi-layer SSH issue

Tags: windows, ssh, filesystems

So I am trying to use WinFSP and SSHFS on Windows 11 to get a local copy of a remote system. I have successfully gotten the file explorer tool "Map Network Drive".
I use: `\\sshfs.kr\'address'` to get the entire system copied and accessible on my computer. The problem arises that when I access that computer via ssh in a command prompt instantiation, I need to access another computer via ssh from within that computer's command line. Is there a way to get a local copy of that second computer's file system to show up on my computer? The only way I could think about maybe making it work is adding another address to the file explorer tool line like `\\sshfs.kr\'address1'\'address2'` but that doesn't work.

I cannot modify the external computer so I can't put an intermediate sshfs folder in there.

Here is the network situation visually and hopefully it will make more sense. This schematic is nonsense electrically. I just thought it might work well as a visual aid.

[image: schematic]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has nothing to do with Electrical Engineering.

Comment: For me your aim is not clear: (1) Do you want to have a real local copy of the file structure (duplicate the files to local) or (2) Do you want to access the remote files by your local explorer (not duplicating them but having a local view on the remote originals)? (3) It is possible to proxy-forward a connection. But what is the reason, you can't access the remote system directly (reduce complexity)? (4) What's about the command line? Do you desire an explorer view of the files or do you want to issue commands on the remote system? — Perhaps you refine your question to get it clearer.